# Javascript functions with different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, variables, onclick

First and foremost, I do apologize if the title for this question may be misleading in anyway. I have a question in regards to a certain function that happens upon clicking a button, in class today my professor taught us some variables in javascript and using them with an onclick for some buttons that we had created in the html, the buttons I have labeled under form tags are as follows:

```js
window.onload=function()
{
 var extraAmmo = 210;
 var maxAmmo = 30;
 var currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
 
 var extraAmmoHud = document.getElementById("extra-ammo");
 var currentAmmoHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");
 
 var shootButton = document.getElementById("shoot-button");
 var reloadButton = document.getElementById("reload-button");
  refreshScreen();
  
 shootButton.onclick=function()
 {
  if(currentAmmo > 0)
  {
   currentAmmo--;
   refreshScreen();
  }
 }
 reloadButton.onclick=function()
 {
  var difference = getDifference();
  if(extraAmmo >= difference)
  {
   currentAmmo += difference;
   extraAmmo -= difference;
  }
  else
  {
   currentAmmo += extraAmmo;
   extraAmmo -= extraAmmo;
  }
  refreshScreen();
  
  function getDifference()
  {
   return maxAmmo -currentAmmo;
  }
 }
 function refreshScreen()
 {
  extraAmmoHud.innerHTML="Extra Ammo: " + extraAmmo;
  currentAmmoHud.innerHTML="Current Ammo: " + currentAmmo;
 }
}
```

```html
 <form>
  <input type="button" value="Shoot" id="shoot-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Reload" id="reload-button" />
  
  <p id="extra-ammo"></p>
  <p id="current-ammo"></p>
 </form>
```

I had a bright idea to add an "unload" button, and what that would to, is instead of clicking and subtracting 1 every time with the "shoot" button, the "unload" button would be a 1 click and say every half-second or so it would automatically subtract 1 until it got to zero. would i need to do anything different? so far I have gotten this far:

```js
window.onload=function()
{
 var extraAmmo = 210;
 var maxAmmo = 30;
 var currentAmmo = maxAmmo;
 
 var extraAmmoHud = document.getElementById("extra-ammo");
 var currentAmmoHud = document.getElementById("current-ammo");
 
 var shootButton = document.getElementById("shoot-button");
 var reloadButton = document.getElementById("reload-button");
  refreshScreen();
  
 shootButton.onclick=function()
 {
  if(currentAmmo > 0)
  {
   currentAmmo--;
   refreshScreen();
  }
 }
 unloadButton.onclick=function()
 {
  if(currentAmmo > 0)
  {
   currentAmmo--;
   refreshScreen();
  }
 }
 reloadButton.onclick=function()
 {
  var difference = getDifference();
  if(extraAmmo >= difference)
  {
   currentAmmo += difference;
   extraAmmo -= difference;
  }
  else
  {
   currentAmmo += extraAmmo;
   extraAmmo -= extraAmmo;
  }
  refreshScreen();
  
  function getDifference()
  {
   return maxAmmo -currentAmmo;
  }
 }
 function refreshScreen()
 {
  extraAmmoHud.innerHTML="Extra Ammo: " + extraAmmo;
  currentAmmoHud.innerHTML="Current Ammo: " + currentAmmo;
 }
}
```

```html
 <form>
  <input type="button" value="Shoot" id="shoot-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Unload" id="unload-button" />
  <input type="button" value="Reload" id="reload-button" />
  
  <p id="extra-ammo"></p>
  <p id="current-ammo"></p>
 </form>
```

I know, it's not much other than a copy and paste of the shootButton.onclick=function(), I am just unsure of what to type.

Comment: forgot to add this in during the question, but I also realized that i was missing "var unloadButton"

Comment: Sounds like you want to use an interval, which will execute a function every x milliseconds?

Comment: This question is way too broad. Is there any way you could pare down the code sample/question?

Answer (score 1):

Just recall the same event using `setTimeout()`.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/73fen9bq/

Basically it gets a reference to the new button:

```
var unloadButton = document.getElementById("unload-button");
```

Then in `unloadButton.onclick`, if `currentAmmo > 0`, it retriggers the same even function:

```
unloadButton.onclick = function () {
    if (currentAmmo > 0) {
        unloadTimer = setTimeout(unloadButton.onclick, 500)
        currentAmmo--;
        refreshScreen();
    } else unloadTimer = null;
}
```

By storing the timer handle in `var unloadTimer;`, you can cancel it when you do another action like so:

```
    if (unloadTimer != null) {
        clearTimeout(unloadTimer);
        unloadTimer = null;
    }
```

Tip: Put that last bit in a new function called 'cancelUnload()', or similar. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the idea James, that does look extremely helpful.